# Should Microsoft Power Platform suite questions be asked in a different community?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

I asked a question about [Power Apps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Power_Platform#Products) in *[Set collection to selected values in PowerApps form when opened in edit mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70098529/powerapp-integrated-form-set-collection-to-selected-values-on-edit)* and even gave it a bounty of 200 points, but it receives very little traffic. I noticed very few questions and a high number without any answers. Is there a different community I am supposed to be using for Power Apps questions?

Comment: There is https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/ but I have no idea what's on-topic there. Your question does seem fine on SO btw, even if there are other communities where it may reach a wider audience.

Comment: @cigien SharePoint is on-topic there :-) PowerApps and other questions generally are on-topic if they relate to working with something in SharePoint like a List or Document Library, etc., like OP's question does.

Comment: It's on-topic but very niche (dedicated PowerApp programmers are rare), so your chances of getting an answer are slim. Not much you can do about that except try and try different places as well (Microsoft forums?)

Comment: [Power BI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Power_BI) is under the same umbrella. Is the reception [to those](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerbi?tab=Newest) similar to [Power Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/powerapps) (not a rhetorical question)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I'm not sure what you're asking, but they're both under the "Power Platform" (along with Power Automate and a couple other things)